# Clicking on Google Result Suggestions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Just for learning purpose, I am trying to click on the third element of the Google Results Suggestions

[image: Clicking on Google Suggestions]

In the above picture, i want to click on qubool hai. My code gets the result suggestions and clicks the 3rd element.

```
List<WebElement> resultsuggestion = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".gssb_m > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr"));
new Actions(driver).click(resultsuggestion.get(2));
```

But Selenium doesn't click on it. Kindly let me know if anything wrong in the above code or suggest me alternative solutions

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using the `Actions()` class in this instance? You probably don't need to. Also, to complete an `Action()` you need to append `.perform()` to the end of your line, `new Actions(driver).click(resultsuggestion.get(2)).perform();`

Comment: Thanks @MarkRowlands for the info.. I used .click first but didn't work. it just highlighted.. so i tried Actions..

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to:

```
WebElement result = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gssb_m > tbody > tr:nth-child(3)"));
result.click();
```

using the `:nth-child` typically is necessary for specifically identifying children. You seem to be trying to find multiples of only 1 `tbody`.

furthermore, using the `Actions` class for a simple click is very unnecessary when you have the `WebElement#click` method.

Comment: it seems clicking on tr:nth-child(3) just highlights it.. so narrowed it to tr:nth-child(3)>td.gssb_a.gbqfsf >div.gsq_a  .. this works.

Comment: right!  you'll have to find the actual `<a />` that you want to click, otherwise it will just do nothing.  Whatever is watching for a click is what you want to click.

Answer (score 0):

Following is another way I found:

```
WebElement result = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gssb_m tr:nth-of-type(3)"));
result.click();
```

`.gssb_m tr:nth-of-type(3)` : Under `class='gssb_m'` element, it looks for third `tr` tag.